# delete text left of space using excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a macro that will scrub down an excel list. I need to take a list of names and remove the first name, so "John Smith" becomes "Smith". I know how to delete text after a space but before a space seems more tricky.

Comment: Wouldnt a simple text to column help you? (your tag VBS should be VBA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a sub that loops through all cells in the named range called "rng_Names" and removes all but the last word.

```
Sub removeAllButLastWord()
    For Each cl In Range("rng_Names")
        cl.Value = Right(cl.Value, Len(cl.Value) - InStrRev(cl.Value, " "))
    Next cl
End Sub
```

**Update**

The following sub Just removes the first word:

```
Sub removeFirstWord()
    For Each cl In Range("rng_Names")
        cl.Value = Right(cl.Value, Len(cl.Value) - InStr(cl.Value, " "))
    Next cl
End Sub
```

**Update the Second**

The following sub removes just the first word, as well as the string " jr" if it exists

```
Sub removeFirstWordAndJR()
    For Each cl In Range("rng_Names")
        cl.Value = Replace(Right(cl.Value, Len(cl.Value) - InStr(cl.Value, " ")), " Jr", "", 1, -1, vbTextCompare)
    Next cl
End Sub
```

Comment: works but i got a few glitches, people with Jr at the end of there names like "john Smith Jr". How can i add escape causes for things like that?

Comment: I should note that running a macro tends to clear the excel history. As such, if something goes wrong, you usually can't undo. Be sure to test any vba you create for potential bugs/weaknesses, and keep backups of your excel workbooks just in case the worst should happen. If you aren't careful, you stand to lose a lot of data.

Comment: Hm... do you want everything but the first word then? I've updated my answer with an altered sub to do just that.

Comment: Thank you! and @Chronicide i understand the risks but i need to edit a 1500+ list of records so a macro is the most time saving i just need to be careful.

Answer (score 1):

use `RIGHT("John Smith",LEN("John Smith")-FIND(" ","John Smith"))`